# jquery slider and jquery kwicks issue

Tags: jquery

I am using the jquery slider from http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/ and the jquery kwciks as shown here http://mottie.github.com/Kwicks/. The problem is when click the first element it expands perfectly, and also the second. but if I click the third element it is not fully displayed. I want to element to be displayed fully. how to achieve this. any ideas will be great

Comment: hi rgin, sorry I have already fixed that. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just picked the expanded element's id and used it as trigger to move forward/backward on the slider. that worked.
Thanks